# Update Stripe fetch call with custom data on payment page

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, stripe-payments, payment

I need to pass the values of some custom input fields on the checkout page where my Payment Element is rendered to the Stripe AJAX call from the documentation. The problem is that the Payment Intent is initialised - and the `fetch` called - on the same page as these inputs, meaning these fields will still be null at this point since the user hasn't filled them in yet.

```
async function initialize() {
const { clientSecret } = await fetch("/payment/stripe", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.querySelector('input[name="_token"]').value,
    },
}).then((r) => r.json());

elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret, appearance });

const paymentElement = elements.create("payment", options);
paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
paymentElement.on("ready", function () {
    document.querySelector(".loading-spinner").style.display = "none";
});
}
```

I therefore can't pass in this data during the `initialise()` function, and need to do so on submit instead. I've managed to successfully pass the values to the server by adding a second `fetch` call to the same endpoint inside the `handleSubmit()` function:

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
setLoading(true);

// Second fetch to pass custom fields
await fetch("/payment/stripe", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.querySelector('input[name="_token"]').value,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: document.querySelector("#name").value,
        email: document.querySelector("#email").value,
    }),
});

const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
        return_url: process.env.MIX_APP_URL + "/success",
    },
});
```

...but this approach has the ugly side effect of creating an extra Payment Intent that never gets used. Is there any way to add my custom values to the initial `fetch` from inside `handleSubmit()`, or any other cleaner way to accomplish what I want to do here?

Comment: If those data are to be set in Payment Intent, you may update it with [Update Payment Intent API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update) before confirming the Payment Intent.

Comment: @yuting That can be done on the server-side, but I'm wanting to grab values from the client-side and pass them to the server.

Comment: As long as `name` and `email` become available and completed, you can pass them to your server to update Payment Intent. It's not necessary to do it with payment button. You could have event listener to check those fields are filled.